# How do I short D+/D- pads on usb type c connector?

Tags: pcb, usb, via, usb-c, usb-2

I am working on a design which utilizes a USB type c connector. My question is what is the proper way of connecting the duplicate D+/D- pads? and do you recommend a specific trace width/ via size?

You can check how I did it in the attached screenshot. I used 8 mil traces and 8/16 mil micro vias.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The traces have to conform to the USB standard, 90 Ohm differential impedance.
The trace width is dictated by your PCB stack-up and height over the ground plane.

Comment: This does not clarify much. What I meant is how do I connect b6 to a6 and b7 to a7?

Comment: @kadhemAlabdulmuhsin Um...with traces?